# xaml in WPF: how to set distances between items in ListvVew - UniformGrid

Tags: xaml, listview, nested, grid, distance

In my C# WPF app I have a ListView, in which I defined the ItemsPanelTemplate as UniformGrid. Within the the UniformGrid I have Checkboxes in several rows and columns. The Checkboxes are styled as Grid (26 x 26) containing a Border (26 x 26) containing an Ellipse.
Now I am wondering, why the horizontal distances between the checkboxes are bigger than the vertical distances. For better visibility I defined the Background properties as follows:
ListView : Red
UniformGrid : Green
CheckBox-Grid : Yellow
CheckBox-Ellipse: Gray

[image]

I tried all properties I know like HorizontalAlignment (center), VerticalAlignment (center), Padding (o), Margin (0), HorizontalItemAlignment (center), ... at all stages but the horizontal distance is always bigger than the vertical. What's the property to have equal horizontal and vertical distances?

Kind regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the Margin of the Grid of the CheckBox (yellow) to "-3,0" but I think this more like a workaround than good coding.